# Re-render child when prop changes in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I need the header of my page to change when a certain action occurs. For this I am making changes inside App.js.

```
function App() {

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  function addList(id) {
    var updated = list
    updated.push(id)
    setList(updated)
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header list={list}></Header>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

Header.js
const Header = ({list}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <p>list</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I need Header to be re-rendered when setList happens. And I would assume that it would since list is being passed as a prop.

I have some other routes that run addList but the problem is that Header is not re-rendered. I'm sure there's a better way to go about this...

Comment: You're not actually changing the reference of the list when you update the state. React sees the props are the same (the list reference is the same), so it skips the update. Try using a boolan that you toggle (`setRefresh(cur => !cur)`), or if the list is important for some reason, `setList([...updated])` to create a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mutate the state directly if it is an object or array.

```
    var updated = list
```

when you do the above both the `updated` and `list` are pointing to the same reference. So when you do this

```
 updated.push(id)
```

You are updating both `updated` and the `list`. The actual problem is in this line

```
setList(updated)
```

when the `setList` function is called react will check is the reference of the object changed? In our case we are not changing the reference even though we are pushing an item. since the reference is not changed react thinks that there is no change happened and will not re-render.

To fix this you need to make a copy of your existing state and concat the new id

```
function addList(id) {
    setList(existingList => ([...existingList, id]))
  }
```

use the `...` operator to create the new copy of the existing list.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason the re-render isn't happening I because "updated" and "list" are basically the same object reference. Can you try

const updated = [...list]

to create a clone of the list object before mutating it